# Can you send multiple Poppi forms on a Merc Mission in New Game Plus?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

According to the Xenoblade Wiki, dispatching any of Poppi's forms on a Merc Mission during [New Game Plus](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/New_Game_Plus_(XC2)#What%27s_New?) will cause all three forms to be treated as on a Merc Mission, preventing you from splitting the forms between multiple missions. However, this doesn't say whether multiple forms can be dispatched on one mission at the same time.

Is it possible to dispatch multiple forms of Poppi on a single Merc Mission if you dispatch them simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Even if on the same mission, you get the message:

> You can only dispatch one model of Poppi at a time.

Comment: I wonder if this is because - while the character menus treat them as separate units - the lore and story considers them as 1 (if I recall correctly that is)

Comment: It's definitely a lore restriction rather than a technical one.